# Como rederizar un formulario según un bucle for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una pequeña practica en react y tengo un formulario que necesito renderizar según un bucle for, pero se me dificulta bastante ya que apenas estoy empezando con react. Este es mi código por el momento, tengo el for en un DidMount, si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias de antemano

```js
export class RenderizadoPrueba extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      value: '',
      nroRenderElemento: 5
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    console.log('Este es el nombre introducido:', this.state.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      for (let indexRender = 0; indexRender < this.state.nroRenderElemento; indexRender++) {
      const nroRender = [indexRender];
      console.log('nro de render:', nroRender)
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div> 
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Introduzca su Nombre:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `for` no es imposible pero mas fácil usando algo como `.map()`

```js
class RenderizadoPrueba extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      nroRenderElemento: 5,
      inputs: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      inputs: [...Array(this.state.nroRenderElemento)].map((input, i) =>
        <input 
            name = {i}
        />
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div > {
        this.state.inputs
      } <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < RenderizadoPrueba / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, y como haría para que ademas de renderizar los inputs según el .map , pueda guardar los datos de cada uno de los inputs en un state diferente cuando le de al botón submit?

Comment: Si no son dinámicos los inputs, puedes crear un `state` por cada input supongamos, en donde el onChange/handleChange cambia también ese `state`, es decir que siempre tenemos *actualizado* el `value`. Si los inputs son dinámicos habría que hacer lo mismo pero creando un objeto o array dentro del state en el mismo momento que creas los inputs, luego a cada input le puedes asignar el mismo handleChange y que actualice el valor del state, pero ahora dentro de un objeto u array dentro del state.  Para ello tendrías que pasar alguna referencia, por ejemplo el `i` del ciclo.

Comment: Si, los inputs serian dinámicos, me podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo por favor